# redirect with route on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am trying to routing the url to some Controllers that are in different folder than the url show... I think it is better an example, I have something like this:

```
$route['admin']             = 'admin/admin';
$route['admin/register']    = 'admin/login/register';
$route['admin/newuser']     = 'admin/login/newuser';
$route['admin/logout']      = 'admin/login/logout';
$route['admin/login']       = 'admin/login';
$route['']                  = 'admin/admin';
```

All of them are working, but last. What I want to do is that someone type www.mydomain.com the system use the controller admin (placed on the folder admin), but  I am getting a 404 always.

A fast, but not elegant solution I am thinking (but I wouldn´t want to do) is modifying the 404 file and test if there is no segment, and then redirect.

Any other idea?? Thank you.

Comment: `$route['default_controller'] = 'admin/admin'` ?

Comment: As @Schultzie wrote, just before custom routes. Check docs to see how it should look like.

Comment: When you need to use codeigniter 3 default controller the controller file will have to be in controllers > Admin.php can not use sub directories for default controller. As here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#reserved-routes `$route['default_controller'] = 'admin'` any other route you should be able to use sub directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Remove `$route[''] = 'admin/admin';`

**Step 2:**
In order to redirect to `admin/admin` when the user type URL `www.mydomain.com`, then you should do like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'admin/admin';
```

Then it will redirect to `admin controller` and `admin method` if no controller after `www.mydomain.com`.

Have nice routing!

Comment: Thanks @Imran, only a little thing... it redirect me to admin controller placed on the admin folder... and it use the index function. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You must set default controller for default page when user click you page

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin";
```

it's set your default view for homepage

Comment: Thanks @yudijohn. Finally I use the Imran solution. $route['default_controller'] = 'admin/admin'; I tried yours, but it doesn´t work, I think (reading all comments) that it could work on codeigniter 3, but I am using codeigniter 2... sorry I didn´t give this info before.

Answer (score 1):

In `config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'admin';
$route['404_override'] = 'admin';
```

When 404 occur it will load method which you provide in `$route['404_override']`.

Comment: On codeigniter 3 default controller will not work with 'admin/admin' will have to be `$route['default_controller'] = 'admin';` Will work if you use HMVC

Comment: @EloyFernándezFranco  did you check this ?

Comment: Thanks @abdulla, I try your solution, but it isn´t complete... I am using CI2 (sorry, I didn´t put this info before) and maybe it is the cause, I need to make $route['default_controller'] = 'admin/admin'; and about the 404_override... what exactly mus to do?? I write www.domain.com/jdjdjdfjs and it always shows me the 404 error page. Thank you.

Comment: When 404 occur it will load method which you provide in `$route['404_override']`